# can't get BC1 texture compression to work with Vulkan on Android

Tags: android, c++, vulkan

I am a new bee on Vulkan I am trying to draw a simple quad with a texture using BC1 compression. I modified the google sample below to accomplish this task.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials/tree/master/tutorial05_triangle

It only works if I use VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM but this is not what I need. I want VK_FORMAT_BC1_RGB_UNORM_BLOCK. I believe the problem is with these lines of the code

```
    if (!compressed) {
      for (int32_t y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
        unsigned char *row = (unsigned char *) ((char *) data + layout.rowPitch * y);
        for (int32_t x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
          row[x * 4] = imageData[(x + y * imgWidth) * 4];
          row[x * 4 + 1] = imageData[(x + y * imgWidth) * 4 + 1];
          row[x * 4 + 2] = imageData[(x + y * imgWidth) * 4 + 2];
          row[x * 4 + 3] = imageData[(x + y * imgWidth) * 4 + 3];
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      memcpy((void*)data, (void*)imageData, tiny_bc1_texture_size);
    }

    vkUnmapMemory(device.device_, tex_obj->mem);
```

notice that the uncompressed version takes account the rowPitch, but for the BC1 (compressed) I don't really get rowPitch. It is compressed, there should be just one stream of bytes. I know Vulkan have some rules on how the memory is copied. But the BC1 texture I have is a tiny test texture (8x8) generated by the PVRTexTool. See screenshot below. And it's raw size after compression is only 32-bytes. So it should align correctly, this is why I use memcpy.

[image]

I also did not want to deal with loading resources, so I saved the file as C and include directly into the project as below.

```
static const unsigned char tiny_bc1_texture[] = {

/* Texture Data */
    0xff,0xff,0x00,0xf8,0x00,0x14,0x14,0x00,0xff,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0x00,0x14,0x14,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x1f,0x00,0x04,0x54,0x54,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x1f,0x00,0x10,0x15,0x15,0x00,
};

static const unsigned char tiny_bc1_texture_w = 8;
static const unsigned char tiny_bc1_texture_h = 8;
static const unsigned char tiny_bc1_texture_size = sizeof(tiny_bc1_texture);
```

But when I run the program this is what I get:

[image]

And when I run the program with uncompressed data (VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM). It looks correct as below:

[image]

I included my full test project on github so I did not want to make this thread too big. But the file that matters is this one:

https://github.com/gmmo/vulkan/blob/main/vulkan_tests/triangle_texture/app/src/main/cpp/VulkanMain.cpp

and the texture creation starts around line 485

```
VkImageCreateInfo image_create_info = {
      .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO,
      .pNext = nullptr,
      .flags = 0,
      .imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D,
etc..
```

The full project is hosted below and if you can even try to build (it should have no dependencies) but you will need a Vulcan enabled phone (like S22 for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S22)

https://github.com/gmmo/vulkan

Anyway, I am stuck and can't get this BC1 texture to work.

Any leads I greatly appreciate.

thank you.

Comment: Does your hardware actually support BC1? Because most mobile GPUs *don't*.

Comment: It's been a long time since I implemented this, but IIRC the trick is that you must upload via a staging buffer, not via a staging image. See the first tip [here](https://xlgames-inc.github.io/posts/vulkantips/) to get you started.

Comment: @NicolBolas it should it is a Galaxy S22, plus when I create the format it does not give me any errors.